# obtener el máximo numeros consecutivo [números- números]

Tags: mysql, laravel

tengo el siguiente problema, en las factura se tiene un consecutivo de la siguiente forma [122-01], según la imagen que subir en los campos de código se tiene un numeros y despues viene un carácter y números  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] que tengo  y necesito en una consulta mysql  busca el valor máximo de primer grupo de números y aumenta el valor, y mi primera solución es crear otro dos campos que tenga eso valores

y mi posible soluccion es

```
        $resul = ArbolesModel::max('id'); 
        $Arboles = ArbolesModel::findOrFail($resul);

        $porciones = explode("-", $Arboles->codigo);
        echo " " . $porciones[0] . " - " . $porciones[1] . "<br>";
        $porciones[0]++; // porción1
        $porciones[1]; // porción2
        echo " " . $porciones[0] . " - " . $porciones[1] . "<br>";
```

Comment: cual seria el problema entonces si ya tenes una solucion?

Comment: se busca el último registro, pero no el valor máximo de consecutivos

Answer (score 0):

asegurate de usar un guion en vez de rayapiso como separador, luego puedes hacer esto

select  SUBSTRING_INDEX(codigo,'-',1) 'ordenar' from tu tabla order by ordenar desc

Comment: Pero como traduces esa consulta a Eloquent o al Query Builder?

Comment: Para este caso yo no usaria el ORM si no que construiria la consulta directamente en mysql y se la pasa con la funcion que debe tener para realizar selects

Comment: aunque no uses el ORM, deberás usar el query builder, dado lo cual considero necesario le adaptes la respuesta a ese escenario, ya que esta trabajando con Lravel